# Rails preloading polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have the following model relations:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many transactions
end
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer
   belongs_to :ta_type, polymorphic: true
end 

class Downpament < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :transaction, as: :ta_type
end 
 class Installemnt < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :transaction, as: :ta_type
end
```

I am able to preload the polymorphic association like this:

```
#app/model/transaction.rb 
def index
  ...
  transactions = self.includes(:ta_type, customer:[:location])
  ...
end
```

But i need a condition on the customer. This query below is also working.

```
transactions = self.includes(customer:[:location]).
    where(customer: {office_id: office_id})
```

however the composition of these two does not work

```
transactions = self.includes(:ta_type, customer:[:location]).
    where(customer: {office_id: office_id})
```

breaks and throws

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 113ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError (Cannot eagerly load the  polymorphic association :ta_type):
```

I found [this](https://makandracards.com/makandra/28347-eager-loading-polymorphic-associations) excellent post describing the problem i have. But i am not able to get it to work.

I tried to use a separated join and a preload together with a join resulting in the same exception.

```
 transactions = self.
     preload(:ta_type, customer:[:location]]).
     joins(:ta_type).
     where(customer: {office_id: office_id})
```

The `preload_assocications` methods seems to be a good idea, but it was removed from rails 3.0.9.

How is it possible to preload the polymorphic association together with the condition properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eager Load Depending on Type of Association in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773318/eager-load-depending-on-type-of-association-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Can you tell about `office_id`. Is it column of Transaction or just a some variable from outside?